# ASP.NET MVC - Resend confirmation email with WebSecurity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Trying to use the WebSecurity and if my user loses, needs to resend, or otherwise changes their email, their does not seem to be any way to reset your confirmation token via the WebSecurity classes.

How do I reset the confirmation token for WebSecurity in Asp.NET MVC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be support for this in the WebSecurity type. I was forced to query the database directly. Since I was using EF my code looked like the following:

```
    public string GetConfirmationToken(string email)
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            var tsqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT [ConfirmationToken] FROM [webpages_Membership] WHERE [UserId] IN (SELECT [UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE [Email] LIKE '{0}')", email);
            return db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(tsqlQuery).First();
        }
    }
```